# Display Woocommerce Orders for specific author

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic, order

I tried finding lot of options and used lot of functions so far in my woocommerce theme but i am unable to find any solution for this issue. This platform is my my only hope so far.

What I want?
I have multiple authors that I have created using roles. In my shopping website these authors are publishing their products and each product has a user role assigned with the following function in my theme:

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_74054_add_author_woocommerce', 999 );
function wpse_74054_add_author_woocommerce() {
add_post_type_support( 'product', 'author' );
}
```

I used the same function for Order post type but it is not working as per my requirements.

My Requirements:
Now when someone order's a product then the individual product or a multiple product get's displayed in the order section of admin and in all my author's dashboard.
What I want is: Specific author should only see it's own product orders and not other author product orders, and admin should be the only one who should see every product orders.

A prompt reply would be much appreciated.

Comment: Best thing to do here is ask this question at: https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/topics/200102403-05-WooCommerce. I'm sure there's a hook that will allow you to filter orders based on who's logged in. Here's the list of available hooks: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: The community is no longer accepting the questions, is there any other way I can find solution.

Comment: I guess they moved their free support to the wordpress.org plugin support system: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce